# Is there a way to assign enum values from variable in Python?

Tags: python, enums

Here's my problem.
At first, I implemented in the code something like this:

```py
class HttpMethod(enum.Enum):
    GET = requests.get
    POST = requests.post
    ...

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.value(*args, **kwargs)
```

But now I want to call `session.get` instead of `requests.get` from the following class, but I don't want to make `session` a global variable to my module.

```py
class HttpPooling:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        retries = Retry(**kwargs)
        self.session.mount("http://", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
        self.session.mount("https://", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
```

I tried many solutions to do obtain such result, but never succeeded, any idea ?
I focused my tests on `__ignore__` from aenum and `__init_subclass__` but I feel like there might be a simplistic way that I can't figure out myself.

Is there a way to do something like this:

```py
    class HttpMethod(enum.Enum):
        pool = HttpPooling()
        GET = pool.session.get
        POST = pool.session.post
```

Comment: Your example doesn't show how you would use the enum.

Comment: @EthanFurman I've update my post to add a hint of a usage. Tell me if it is still unclear.

Comment: `Enum` exists to add names to constants so our code is easier to write, read, and maintain.  This doesn't really look like a good use-case for enum.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did finally come to a solution with the package aenum which comes with an `__ignore__` field for enums.

```py
class HttpMethod(Enum):
    POST, GET, PUT, PATH, DELETE = range(1, 6)

    __pool = HttpPooling()
    __ignore__ = ("__pool",)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.value.__repr__()

    @property
    def value(self):
        return partial(getattr(self.__pool.session, self.name.lower()))

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.value(*args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def keys(cls):
        return cls.__members__.keys()
```

Comment: Why is using an enum better than using a normal class?